# Laravel recursive where for recursive relationship

Tags: laravel, nested, relationship

I have a table hobbies like this:

```
-id
-name
-parent_id
```

and my model

```
public function sub_hobbies(){
    return $this->hasMany(Hobbies::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function parent_hobbies(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Hobbies::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function allsub(){
    return $this->sub_hobbies()->with('allsub');
}

public function allparent(){
    return $this->parent_hobbies()->with('allparent');
}
```

What i want is to get all hobbies which are not child or grand child of given hobbies

example i have this list:

```
-hobbies 1
  -hobbies 11
  -hobbies 12
    -hobbies 121
    -hobbies 122
  -hobbies 13
-hobbies 2
  -hobbies 21
  -hobbies 22
    -hobbies 221
    -hobbies 222
  -hobbies 23
-hobbies 3
  -hobbies 31
  -hobbies 32
    -hobbies 321
    -hobbies 322
  -hobbies 33
```

if i give id of hobbies 1, i want all hobbies except hobbies 11, 12, 121, 122, 13

Comment: `Hobby::doesntHave('parent_hobbies')->orDoesntHave('parent_hobbies.parent_hobbies')->...`

Comment: i have unlimited tree of data but i just give a part of data, so it's not worth using this way

Comment: It's just retrieve the first hierarchie, but i want to retrieve all but excluding the hobbies selected and his child and grand child

Answer (score 0):

So i found a little way to make run what i want to do but i don't know if it's the right way:

```
 // get hobbies and exlude given hobbies and his child line
    public function scopeIsNotLine($query, $id){
        // get all hobbies to exclude by id and his child line
        $hobbies = Hobbies::with('allsub')->where('id', $id)->get()->toArray(); 

        // transform result to array of id of hobbies to exclude
        $exclude = collect($this->flatten($hobbies))->map(function ($item) {
            return collect($item)
                ->only(['id'])
                ->all();
        })->flatten()->all();

        // get hobbies where id not in exluded hobbies
        return $query->whereNotIn('id', $exclude)->whereDoesntHave('is_archive');
    }

    // transform nested result to simple array without nest hierarchie
    private function flatten($array) {
        $result = [];
        foreach ($array as $item) {
            if (is_array($item)) {
                $result[] = array_filter($item, function($array) {
                    return ! is_array($array);
                });
                $result = array_merge($result, $this->flatten($item));
            }
        }
        return array_filter($result);
    }
```

- Firts i retrieve the hobbies selected with his all child and grand child
- Second, i transform the result into flatten array (list all without nested relationship) with the function flatten that i created
- Third i transform again into array of id
- Fourth i use this array in whereNotIn to retrieve all hobbies and exclude the hobbies selected and his child line
- Fifth i used my scope like `Hobbies::isNotLine('the-id-selected')->get();`

In result i got all hobbies excluding the hobbies i selected, and his child and grand child